# Viewer node in compositing doesn't show anything

Tags: node-editor, render-layers, compositing-nodes

Viewer node in compositing doesn't show anything, I've rendered the image, unplugged and replugged the nodes, but it never displays anything for some reason.

[uploaded the blender file here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1piMf1XWZJYkSeNpRlchPTKF7OQ9ui_rr/view?usp=sharing)

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Enable the `Use Nodes` check box in the compositor and refresh the Viewer node with the `Reset Nodes` operator <kbd>Backspace</kbd> from the bundled `Node Wrangler` addon or change anything in the node graph to trigger an update.

Comment: It works now, thank you so so much!!

Comment: @llamab if Stack Exchange answer is useful to you, you should upvote it, if it solves your problem, you should also accept it as the correct answer.